# Node JS multiple http request missing response

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

Hello I am working on node js http request with a loop and its size is 1728 and its response is missing like it stuck at 1727 kindly help me I am trying to fix this problem for three days.

```
for ( let i = 0 ; i < playerLength ; i++ ) {
for ( let j = startYear ; j < currentYear ; j++ ) {

    var playerSeasonData = {};
    playerSeasonData.url = me.config.sport.url + league + '/v2/JSON/PlayerSeasonStatsByPlayer/'+ j +'/' + playerData[i].playerID;
    playerSeasonData.method = 'GET';
    playerSeasonData.headers = {};
    playerSeasonData.headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':'**********************'};

    me.request( playerSeasonData ,function(  error, response, data  ){
        count ++;
    )};
}
```

}

Comment: how do you infer that requests "are missing response"? is it always the same number of requests? try to minimize the example to be smaller and self-contained without unspecified variables (what is the value of `playerLength` etc)?. Note that responses are asynchronous, if you read `count` somewhere out of the loop, the value will likely be wrong, as the counter will change over time as new responses arrive

Comment: I am counting the request inside of the loop and the player length is 557 and try to minimize the size but still i am facing the same problem ..

Comment: help me if you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that your function is returning before all the http requests have been completed.

Consider promisifying `me.request` via `bluebird` and then return a `Promise.all`. Here's an example: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

Comment: I will to implement this then I will tell you thank for the response

Comment: I implemented promisifying me.request via bluebird and then promise all its did not work it stuck at 1698 or 1643

Comment: it worked for me without promise all thank for the response

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the simple solution of using <= instead of <. Hard to say from the code you are showing, but that might be the difference between 1728 & 1727.

Comment: No need to do this man I initialize count variable before loop